# Xlib: XCreateSimpleWindow steal steals focus

Tags: linux, x11, xlib

I have a question regarding the XCreateSimpleWindow function in Xlib.
I have a small screen on my graphical panel, which steals the keyboard input once this function gets called, and does not allow me to navigate/do anything, on the rest of the screen, e.g. use keys to navigate in the menu or similar.

The small screen is used for video streaming, and I have tried to use the function XSetInputFocus on the parent window, but that does not seem to help. I would be grateful if somebody could give me some ideas on how to solve this issue. Please let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: Is a window manager running?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiyble example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your programming specific problem. Also make sure to visit the [SO's Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask good questions.

Comment: You should post a code before we can give any reasonable answer